# Add property to object only if it is not undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following object:

```
let params = {
  limit: limit,
  offset: 15,
  status: "completed",
  product_id: this.route.snapshot.queryParams.product_id,
};
```

The above object contain parameters that filter my data source.

`this.route.snapshot.queryParams.product_id` is a query/get parameter

> ?product_id=123

However if this value is not present it's undefined. So I do not want to add `product_id` member to the parameters object if this value is undefined.

#### If it is `undefined` the object should look like:

```
let params = {
  limit: limit,
  offset: 15,
  status: "completed",
};
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Inline solution:

```
let params = {
  limit: limit,
  offset: 15,
  status: "completed",
  ...this.route.snapshot.queryParams.product_id && {product_id: this.route.snapshot.queryParams.product_id},
};
```

Or shorter:

```
const product_id = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.product_id
let params = {
  limit: limit,
  offset: 15,
  status: "completed",
  ...product_id && {product_id},
};
```

Comment: Im working with Angular so i prefer this es6 solution. thank you.

Comment: I've been hoping to find something like this for a while, very nice

Answer (score 5):

Add product_id only if it is undefined

```
let params = {
        limit: limit,
        offset: 15,
        status: "completed",
    };

if(this.route.snapshot.queryParams.product_id)
   params['product_id'] = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.product_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also try:

```
let param = { product_id:this.route.snapshot.queryParams.product_id }
params = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.product_id ? {...params, ...param} : params ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this inline, but

```
let params:object;
if ( this.route.snapshot.queryParams.product_id){
    params = {
            limit: limit,
            offset: 15,
            status: "completed",
            product_id: this.route.snapshot.queryParams.product_id,
        };
        }
else{
    params = {
            limit: limit,
            offset: 15,
            status: "completed",
        };  
}
```

will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with object destructuring as below

```
var param = {
            limit: 5,
            offset: 15,
            status: "completed",
            product_id: undefined,
        };
var { product_id, ...rest } = param

param = { ...(product_id && { product_id }), ...rest }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I've done this in the past, I've gone with something similar to the example below. I feel like there's probably a better way of doing this, but I've yet to find one.

```js
const removeUndefinedValues = objectIn => Object.keys(objectIn)
  .reduce((prev, curr) => {
    return objectIn[curr] !== undefined ?
      {
        ...prev,
        [curr]: objectIn[curr]
      } : prev
  }, {})

let paramsOne = {
    limit: 0,
    offset: 15,
    status: "completed",
    product_id: undefined,
}

let paramsTwo = {
    limit: 0,
    offset: 15,
    status: "completed",
    product_id: "A value",
}

console.dir(removeUndefinedValues(paramsOne))
console.dir(removeUndefinedValues(paramsTwo))
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think you should let `product_id` be undefined and do a check if its there later down the line but you could do the following:

```
let params = {
  limit: limit,
  offset: 15,
  status: "completed",
};

if(this.route.snapshot.queryParams.product_id) {
  params['product_id'] = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.product_id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*What do you think about the following*

```
const constantParams= {
   limit: limit,
   offset: 15,
   status: "completed",
}
let yourDynamicObject = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.product_id 
? {...constantParams, product_id: this.route.snapshot.queryParams.product_id}
: this.paramsWichAreAlwaysThere
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to achieve this. I'll point out two of them.
you can simply use an if statement for adding `product_id` field

```
let product_id = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.product_id;
if(product_id) {
    params.product_id = product_id;
}
```

or

you could use split operator

```
let product_id = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.product_id;
let params = {
    limit: limit,
    offset: 15,
    status: "completed",
    ...product_id ? {product_id} : {},
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```
let params = {
        limit: limit,
        offset: 15,
        status: "completed",
    };

if (this.route.snapshot.queryParams.product_id) {
   params["product_id"] = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.product_id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across same issue, created a function for that, easy to reuse:

```
const isEmpty = (value) => (value === undefined || value === null || value === '');
const isNotEmpty = (value) => !isEmpty(value);

const newEntry = (key, value) => {
  const newObj = {};
  if (isNotEmpty(value)) {
    newObj[key] = value;
  }
  return { ...newObj };
};
```

Code would look like this now:

```
const params = {
  limit,
  offset: 15,
  status: 'completed',
  ...newEntry(product_id, this.route.snapshot.queryParams.product_id),
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
  const product_id = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.product_id;

  let params = Object.assign({
            limit: limit,
            offset: 15,
            status: "completed"
        }, product_id ? {product_id} : {});
```

Answer (score -1):

How about constructing params object with 3 members and later append based on condition.

```
let params = {
  limit: limit,
  offset: 15,
  status: "completed",
};
var value = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.product_id;
if (value) {
  params.product_id = value
}
```